# Gridview with GridViewAdapter how to set onclick listener in Gridview and not GridViewAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I want to have an onlongclicklistener on my gridview elements that opens an popup menu.
But im not able to do this unless i put that onclicklistener in the gridviewadapter. Im gonna use the itemlist on popupmenu to float an new fragment request to the activity and change values in the arraylist in activities.

So i want to keep this "inhouse of the fragment" and not in the GridViewAdapter. is it not possible to set an onclicklistener directly on gridview when using gridviewadapter?

PT_Activity;

```
public class PT_Activity extends Activity implements Serializable{

ArrayList<PictureItem> pictureArray;
FragmentTransaction ft;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_fragment);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        GetData();

        Bundle extra = new Bundle();
        extra.putSerializable("pictureArray", pictureArray);
        ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        PT_Fragment pt_fragment = new PT_Fragment();
        pt_fragment.setArguments(extra);
        ft.add(R.id.singleFragmentContainer, pt_fragment, "pt_fragment");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

public ArrayList<PictureItem> GetData(){
    if(pictureArray == null){
        FileInteraction fileInteraction = new FileInteraction();
        pictureArray = (fileInteraction.getArrayOfPictureItemFromFolder(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PictureTalk/PictureTalk/"));
    }
    return pictureArray;
}}
```

PT_Fragment

```
public class PT_Fragment extends Fragment implements Serializable {

private PT_Activity pt_activity;
private View view;
private GridView gridView;
private PictureGridViewAdapter pictureGridViewAdapter;
private ArrayList<PictureItem> pt_Array;
private Bundle extra;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pt_activity = (PT_Activity) getActivity();
    extra = getArguments();
    pt_Array = (ArrayList<PictureItem>) extra.getSerializable("pictureArray");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picturetalk_main_category, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.PictureGrid1);
    pictureGridViewAdapter = new PictureGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
    R.layout.picturetalk_picture_grid, pt_Array);
    gridView.setAdapter(pictureGridViewAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SelectionMenu();
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private void SelectionMenu() {
    PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), gridView);
    popMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.picturetalk_popup_menu, popMenu.getMenu());
    popMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.edit:


                 //  PT_EditPictureFragment pt_editPictureFragment = new   
                 PT_EditPictureFragment();

                   //  Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditPicture.class);
                   //  intent.putExtra("itemUUID", item.getId());
                    String s = new String("");
                    // context.startActivity(intent);
                   // break;

                case R.id.remove:
                    FileInteraction fileInteraction = new FileInteraction();
                    //fileInteraction.deleteFilesAndFolder(item.getImagePath());
                    //item.setTitle("");
                    //notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;

                default:
                    //

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    popMenu.show();

}}
```

PictureGridViewAdapter

```
public class PictureGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList<PictureItem> data;


public PictureGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                       ArrayList data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    final PictureItem item = (PictureItem) data.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getImagePath()));
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (item.getSoundPath() != null) {
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), Uri.parse(item.getSoundPath()));
                    mp.start();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
/*
    row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
            popMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.picturetalk_popup_menu, popMenu.getMenu());
            popMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                        case R.id.edit:


                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditPicture.class);
                            intent.putExtra("itemUUID", item.getId());
                            String s = new String("");
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            break;

                        case R.id.remove:
                            FileInteraction fileInteraction = new FileInteraction();
                            fileInteraction.deleteFilesAndFolder(item.getImagePath());
                            item.setTitle("");
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;

                        default:
                            //

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popMenu.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    */
    return row;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}}
```

Comment: Ive searched through both stackoverflow and google for solutions. Those that experience this problem seem to get it fixed by setting all the element (buttons,text etc in the gridview (in my case gridviewadapter)) to setFocusable=false, setClickable=false and setFocusableInTouchMode=false. Im my case it didnt help. Still nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that when you call `row.setOnClickListener` you are making your rows clickable (overriding whatever you put in the XML). The means that all click processing, which includes the long-click timer Android uses inside the View class, happens for your row and not your GridView. You need to handle both types of clicks in one place, but you have two options.

Option 1: You can both types of clicks in the fragment, by using `setOnItemClickListener` and `setOnItemLongClickListener`. Like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picturetalk_main_category, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.PictureGrid1);
    pictureGridViewAdapter = new PictureGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
        R.layout.picturetalk_picture_grid, pt_Array);
    gridView.setAdapter(pictureGridViewAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SelectionMenu();
            return true;
        }
    });
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // start-media code could go in fragment or adapter
            pictureGridViewAdapter.startMediaPlayer(position);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Option 2: You can both types of clicks in the adapter. Since you want to keep the popup menu in the fragment, you could give the adapter a back-pointer to the fragment in the adapter's constructor, and then call a method in the fragment to show it.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picturetalk_main_category, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.PictureGrid1);
    pictureGridViewAdapter = new PictureGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
        R.layout.picturetalk_picture_grid, pt_Array);
    pictureGridViewAdapter.setFragment(this); // or add a constructor parameter
    gridView.setAdapter(pictureGridViewAdapter);
    ...
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            fragment.showPopupMenu(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tried Option 1 earlier, didnt work even if i put all of them onclicklisteners out to the fragment, and set buttonsclick false etc in the gridviewadapter. Will test ut option 2

Comment: How would you get ahold of the fragment from the GridViewAdapter?

Comment: In the onCreateView version in my answer (option 2), I've added a new function setFragment(this) to call on your adapter. You can either do that, or you can add a fragment parameter to the adapter's constructor, on the previous line. You can either let the adapter know specifically about your fragment class, or you can make a new interface that the fragment implements. The interface approach is of course what you want if the adapter was used in other places, but it's also a nice approach in this case.